# Laravel how to Join other database tables?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel-5

I have 2 tables but different databases, I want to join those tables together?
Example:

```
SELECT CharID,StrUserID
FROM SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._User as us
     JOIN SRO_VT_ACCOUNT.dbo.TB_User u ON us.UserJID = u.JID
ORDER BY StrUserID ASC
```

Comment: So what is your question? What you have "asked" isn't actually a question, it's a statement that you've just ended with a question mark. Why isn't the above working?

Comment: So long as both those databases are on the same SQL Server instance and the user running the query has access to both databases and SELECT permissions on the tables, that will work.

Comment: Little googling would solve you the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your tables that you are looking to join belongs to a database that is part of the same SQL Server Instance, you could use something like:

```
SELECT CharID,StrUserID
FROM SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._User as us
INNER JOIN SRO_VT_ACCOUNT.dbo.TB_User u ON us.UserJID = u.JID
INNER JOIN [DatabaseName].[Schema].[TableName] AS Alias ON u.JID = alias.ID
ORDER BY StrUserID ASC
```

If your tables that you are looking to join belongs to a different database that is being part of another SQL Server Instance, you could do it through `Linked Server`:

```
SELECT CharID,StrUserID
FROM SRO_VT_SHARD.dbo._User as us
INNER JOIN SRO_VT_ACCOUNT.dbo.TB_User u ON us.UserJID = u.JID
INNER JOIN [MyLinkedServer].[DatabaseName].[Schema].[TableName] AS Alias ON u.JID = alias.ID
ORDER BY StrUserID ASC
```

Comment: How can I do it with laravel 5?,  i use sql server.

Comment: I don't know Laravel, sorry. Anyway, you can answer another question here.